# Highcharts naming of individual bubbles

Tags: highcharts

The new Highcharts v3.0 bubble chart looks great. Is it possible to annotate and display each bubble with a name/some text?
Thanks, Nigel.

Answer (score 14):

There are two things you need to do.

First, name each data point (bubble):

> ```
> data: [
>   { name: 'Alice', x: 3.5, y: 4, z: 5}, 
>   { name: 'Eve', x: 7, y: 7, z: 3}, 
>   { name: 'Carol', x: 4, y: 8, z: 6}
> ]
> ```

Second, create a data label formatter:

> ```
> dataLabels: {
>   enabled: true,
>   formatter: function() {
>     return this.point.name;
>   }
> }
> ```

You can see this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/franzo/JuGDp/1/

Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Very helpful! Based on your example, I created another reference: http://jsfiddle.net/csyyb5da/

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want to display, it should be possible. The bubble charts will allow the same options as any other highcharts. The easiest way is to use dataLabels http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.scatter.dataLabels

```
       dataLabels:{
           enabled:true
       }
```

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-datalabels-box/

If that isn't flexible enough for you, it is possible to draw whatever you want on the chart using the underlying renderer http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer. This is a bit harder, but. Fairly straight forward once you get the hang of it.

I've created a small example using datalabels here :http://jsfiddle.net/4nRk6/

Datalabels can be customised with a formatter function, for example:

```
 dataLabels: {
           enabled: true,
           formatter: function() {
                    return this.y +'mm';
           }
 }
```

The full documentation is here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.dataLabels

If you want extra information on the bubbles, you may need to format your data series as follows:

```
[
    {x:1, y:5, bubbleText:"Bubble 1"},
    {x:2, y:15, bubbleText:"Bubble 2"},
    {x:3, y:5, bubbleText:"Bubble 3"}
]
```

Inside your dataLabel, you can then reference this.point.bubbleText as well as this.x and this.y.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.I'm struggling with this. Can anybody post an example of a bubble charts with labels on the bubbles? Or is this not "meant" to be a feature?

Comment: Hi, Ive updated my post with a link to a working example. http://jsfiddle.net/4nRk6/

Comment: Hi Steve,  Many thanks for this. What I need is a label that is textual - so not just the x value shown as in your example.  Just like in other charts where we include names in a series?  Not sure how to include this laongside the x,y, size attributes...  Nigel.

Comment: Thanks again. Not sure how I would progress from there to programmatically label bubble 1, say "Project ABC", bubble 2 "Project DEF" etc.  I've done plenty of great looking Highcharts graphs but can't see how we would get a {name:"Project ABC"} associated with a particular bubble!

Comment: Updated to show how points can be defined with additional fields.

Comment: Steve - can you update the jsfiddle eg to demo this? Would really appreciate it - can't see how I would get bubble size AND a label - have tried a few combos...?

Comment: Steve,  that's looking good. I think that's exactly what I am after. Appreciate your help to date!  Nigel.

Comment: Love to - How on earth do I do that!?